# XenAPI Library - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, virtualization, xen

In two official repos, one from XenServer and the other from XCP-NG, there are the sources for the XenAPI library, the problem is that they have to be compiled, they use OCAML and OPAM.

The repos are:

https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api

https://github.com/xcp-ng/xen-api/tree/master

The issue is that I'm trying to compile them with WSL (I tried first with Debian, and then with Ubuntu), and even though I follow the step by step I can't compile them, either because of package reference problems, or because I can't do make , or because when doing all the steps (when it doesn't throw an error) it doesn't find anything to compile in the directory or because of version and compatibility problems with OCAML and OPAM. Previously I used a Debian VM to try to build, same thing, various errors.

The point is that I'm trying to connect from C# to an XCP-NG node to execute commands, but I don't have where to get the library from, can someone give me some info?

I tried to compile de library to connect a node of XCP-NG from C#.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to download compiled ones from https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api/releases?

Comment: @Orifjon the releases contains files with extensions .opam.